# Shouldn't the Hofmann product be preferred in this elimination?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Shouldn't the exocyclic alkene (Hofmann) be the major product? The base is $\ce{t-BuO-}$ (tertiary butoxide ion), which is pretty bulky. I think the Saytzeff product should be the minor product.

Also, the solution says "E2, some E1". It's a 3° alkyl halide (more sterically hindered than 1° and 2°), so shouldn't it undergo E1 elimination?

Comment: You have reasoning already in your picture. Also don't put "thanks" in posts. You can do it in comments.

Comment: I don't understand the reason given, according to that E1 Hoffman elimination should be favoured. Please explain.

Comment: "good base" for mechanism, high temp - isomer

Comment: The base is sterically hindered.

Comment: Maybe it would matter matter in low temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, $\ce{t-BuO-}$ is a bulky base.

But is it bulky *enough* that it can't even abstract a hydrogen from the ring? Nope.

Take a look at this picture of a $\ce{t-BuO-}$ molecules approaching the hydrogen of 1-bromo-1-methyl-cyclopentane.

[image]

Does that $\ce{t-BuO-}$ look like it's struggling to pull that hydrogen out? Definitely not. It's doing what it does with ease.

Comment: The picture given in the question states some conditions. What do you think about their relevance to the Zaitsev Product?